# Why my Matrix Multipication code in c always give the garbage value? (using shared memory and fork)

Tags: c, unix, fork, shared-memory

This is my code in c to do Matrix Multiplication implement fork and shared memory. It seem like the value that I get is the mostly garbage value. Maybe I did not initialize the value of the array C which is the result array first. (I am beginner at C and this is my first time using the shared memory)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#define N 3

void doMulT(int row,int col,int x ,int a[][N],int b[][N],int c[]);
int main()
{
    int Ma[N][N];
    int Mb[N][N];
    int segment_id;
    pid_t pid=-1;

        printf("Input the elements in Matrix A (%dx%d) : \n",N,N);
        for(int k = 0; k<N ;k++)
        {
                for(int d = 0; d<N ; d++)
                {
                        scanf("%d",&Ma[k][d]);
                }
        }
        printf("Input the elements in Matrix B (%dx%d) : \n",N,N);
        for(int k = 0; k<N ;k++)
        {
                for(int d = 0; d<N ; d++)
                {
                        scanf("%d",&Mb[k][d]);
                }
        }

    segment_id = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE,1024, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
        int *C = (int*)shmat(segment_id,NULL,0);

    for(int i=0;i<N*N;i++)
    {
        if(pid != 0)
        {
            pid = fork();
        }
    }

    if(pid == 0)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<N; i++)
        {
            for(int j =0; i<N; j++)
            {
                if(C[i*N+j]==0)
                {
                    doMulT(i,j,N,Ma,Mb,C);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    else
    {
        for(int k =0;k<N*N;k++)
        {
            wait(NULL);
        }
        printf("==========Result==========\n");
            for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
            {
                    for(int j=0; j<N; j++)
                    {
                            printf("%d",C[i*N+j]);
                            printf(" ");
                    }
                    printf("\n");
            }
        }
    shmdt(C);
        shmctl(segment_id, IPC_RMID, NULL);
}

void doMulT(int row,int col,int x ,int a[][N],int b[][N],int c[])
{
        for(int k=0; k<x; k++)
        {
             c[row*x+col]+=a[row][k]*b[k][col];
        }
}
```

The example of the input

```
Input the elements in Matrix A (3x3) :
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
Input the elements in Matrix B (3x3) :
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
```

The output is like

```
6 6 6
123482868 -745374 -2637821
456729394 -98475839 -2884829
```

Comment: Please explain more about what are you trying to achieve using `fork()`

Comment: I want to make each process do the calculation for each position in the matrix.

Comment: Please explain how the exactly child processes are supposed to work together. (which child does what?) Probably you have to explicitly assign a specific part of the work to every individual process. Please [edit] your question to add clarification, don't use comments to answer.

Comment: Is the shared memory zeroed?  The code assumes it is.  It isn't clear how each child determines which cell it should calculate.  The children should probably use the value in `i` to determine the cell it should work on, but that means breaking the child creation loop as soon as a process knows it is a child.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first part of this answer is intended to show the problems in the original program and ways to debug the problems.

I added some `printf` output to see what the processes will do

```
    if(pid == 0)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<N; i++)
        {
            for(int j =0; i<N; j++)
            {
                if(C[i*N+j]==0)
                {
                    printf("process %ld calculating (%d, %d)\n", (long)getpid(), i, j);
                    doMulT(i,j,N,Ma,Mb,C);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and get output like this:

```
process 747 calculating (0, 204)                                                                                                                                                               
process 746 calculating (0, 292)                                                                                                                                                               
process 746 calculating (0, 293)                                                                                                                                                               
process 747 calculating (0, 205)                                                                                                                                                               
process 746 calculating (0, 294)                                                                                                                                                               
process 747 calculating (0, 206)                                                                                                                                                               
process 746 calculating (0, 295)                                                                                                                                                               
process 747 calculating (0, 207)
```

That means the loop for `j` is wrong.

There is a typo:

```
            for(int j =0; i<N; j++)
```

must be

```
            for(int j =0; j<N; j++) // j<N  instead of  i<N
```

In addition I used `memset` to initialize the shared memory with 0.

After fixing the loop I get

```
process 238 calculating (0, 0)                                                                                                                                                              
process 238 calculating (0, 1)                                                                                                                                                              
process 238 calculating (0, 2)                                                                                                                                                              
process 238 calculating (1, 0)                                                                                                                                                              
process 238 calculating (1, 1)                                                                                                                                                              
process 238 calculating (1, 2)                                                                                                                                                              
process 238 calculating (2, 0)                                                                                                                                                              
process 238 calculating (2, 1)                                                                                                                                                              
process 238 calculating (2, 2)                                                                                                                                                              
==========Result==========                                                                                                                                                                  
6 6 6                                                                                                                                                                                       
12 12 12                                                                                                                                                                                    
18 18 18
```

This means that one child did all the work before others got active.

A delay in the processing loop leaves a chance for other processes to get some work.

**Note:** This is not meant as a real solution. The main purpose is to show that you cannot rely on the system to distribute the work between the processes.

It also shows that the matrix multiplication is not a good use case for multiprocessing because the calculation of a matrix cell (at least for a small matrix as in your example) is apparently much faster than the creation of a new process.

```
    if(pid == 0)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<N; i++)
        {
            for(int j =0; j<N; j++)
            {
                if(C[i*N+j]==0)
                {
                    printf("process %ld calculating (%d, %d)\n", (long)getpid(), i, j);
                    doMulT(i,j,N,Ma,Mb,C);
                    sleep(1); // give other processes a chance to do some work
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

For a good solution you have to implement a way to assign a specific task to every child process. One option would be to pass the loop variable `i` (or maybe two separate loop variables for row and column) to the processing function in the child process as shown in the following version.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 3
#define SIZE 1024

void doMulT(int row,int col,int x ,int a[][N],int b[][N],int c[]);
int main()
{
    int Ma[N][N] = {
        {1, 1, 1},
        {2, 2, 2},
        {3, 3, 3}
    };
    int Mb[N][N] = {
        {1, 1, 1},
        {2, 2, 2},
        {3, 3, 3}
    };
    int segment_id;
    pid_t pid=-1;

#if 0
        printf("Input the elements in Matrix A (%dx%d) : \n",N,N);
        for(int k = 0; k<N ;k++)
        {
                for(int d = 0; d<N ; d++)
                {
                        scanf("%d",&Ma[k][d]);
                }
        }
        printf("Input the elements in Matrix B (%dx%d) : \n",N,N);
        for(int k = 0; k<N ;k++)
        {
                for(int d = 0; d<N ; d++)
                {
                        scanf("%d",&Mb[k][d]);
                }
        }
#endif

    segment_id = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, SIZE, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
        int *C = (int*)shmat(segment_id,NULL,0);

    memset(C, 0, SIZE);
    
    for(int i=0; (pid != 0) && (i<N); i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; (pid != 0) && (j<N); j++)
        {
            if(pid != 0)
            {
                pid = fork();
                if(pid == 0)
                {
                    printf("process %ld calculating (%d, %d)\n", (long)getpid(), i, j);
                    doMulT(i,j,N,Ma,Mb,C);
                    exit(0);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    if(pid != 0)
    {
        while(wait(NULL) != -1 || (errno != ECHILD))
        {
            ;
        }
        printf("==========Result==========\n");
            for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
            {
                    for(int j=0; j<N; j++)
                    {
                            printf("%d",C[i*N+j]);
                            printf(" ");
                    }
                    printf("\n");
            }
        }
    shmdt(C);
        shmctl(segment_id, IPC_RMID, NULL);
}

void doMulT(int row,int col,int x ,int a[][N],int b[][N],int c[])
{
        for(int k=0; k<x; k++)
        {
             c[row*x+col]+=a[row][k]*b[k][col];
        }
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
process 7489 calculating (0, 0)                                                                                                                                                             
process 7495 calculating (2, 0)                                                                                                                                                             
process 7496 calculating (2, 1)                                                                                                                                                             
process 7497 calculating (2, 2)                                                                                                                                                             
process 7493 calculating (1, 1)                                                                                                                                                             
process 7490 calculating (0, 1)                                                                                                                                                             
process 7494 calculating (1, 2)                                                                                                                                                             
process 7492 calculating (1, 0)                                                                                                                                                             
process 7491 calculating (0, 2)                                                                                                                                                             
==========Result==========                                                                                                                                                                  
6 6 6                                                                                                                                                                                       
12 12 12                                                                                                                                                                                    
18 18 18
```

Comment: Each child should know exactly which result cell it is supposed to compute, based on the value of `i` when it finds `pid == 0` after the `fork()` (the process creation loop needs some modifications).  Then the sleep is unnecessary.  Using some functions (`be_parental()` and `be_childish()` are my favourite names) would improve the clarity too: `for (i = 0; i < N * N; i++) { if ((pid = fork()) < 0) { …error… } else if (pid == 0) { be_childish(i): } be_parental();` or thereabouts.  The child functions should not return; they should contain an `exit()` call.